# Why do I have to write await multiple times for an async query?

Tags: c#

I admit that there is probably something basic I'm not grasping here, but in the below code, why whould I have to `await` two times the same query?

I'm looking up a person by his email address, which is a database lookup. I call my private function `GetByEmailQueryAsync` which returns a record from the database if found. I use `await` for this call, so I'm sure that a result (if found) is returned.

Why do I have to put the `await` keyword again in the function calling `GetByEmailQueryAsync`? And then again in all functions calling `GetByEmail`. The callers of this function should not care that this function performs some asynchronous task, in my opinion.
Again, I'm probably missing something basic here.

```
public async Task<Person> GetByEmail(string emailAddress)
{
    return await GetByEmailQueryAsync(emailAddress);
}

private async Task<Person> GetByEmailQueryAsync(string emailAddress)
{
    return await DbContext.Set<Person>.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.EmailAddress == emailAddress);
}
```

This is a pretty basic example of what I mean, but I hope you get the gist.

Comment: You don't have to `await` the database query - you can just return the task and `await` that in `GetByEmail`. You can also omit the `await` in `GetByEmail` and just `await` the result from that in the calling code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to await both.

As your `GetByEmail` method is simply calling `GetByEmailQueryAsync`, this would work just as well:

```
public Task<Person> GetByEmail(string emailAddress)
{
    return GetByEmailQueryAsync(emailAddress);
}
```

In fact by not using `await` twice, it means only one `Task` is required, rather than two.

Comment: [Eliding Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html).

Comment: @KirkLarkin yes, that's definitely a good article to read, but none of the mentioned pitfalls apply here.

Answer (score 0):

> Why do I have to put the await keyword again in the function calling GetByEmailQueryAsync? And then again in all functions calling GetByEmail. The callers of this function should not care that this function performs some asynchronous task, in my opinion.

While it would be nice to treat asynchronous code as an implementation detail, that is not possible to do in the C# language.

As a general rule, any method calling an asynchronous method should consume it with `await`, and the calling method itself is also an asynchronous method. So its callers should consume it with `await`, and themselves be asynchronous methods, etc. This "growth" of `async`/`await` through the code base is natural, and it is proper to go [`async` all the way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming).

In *trivial* cases, it is possible to [elide `async`/`await`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html), but even in that case the calling method is still asynchronous.